# How to import bibtex correctly from google scholar?

Tags: biblatex, templates

The format of bibtex file imported from google scholar is different from that of standard one.

The google one looks like:

```
@article{travlos1987corporate,
  title={Corporate takeover bids, methods of payment, and bidding firms' stock returns},
  author={Travlos, Nickolaos G},
  journal={The Journal of Finance},
  volume={42},
  number={4},
  pages={943--963},
  year={1987},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

The standard one looks:

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
```

Do we have to manually change all the brackets to quotation marks? That seems really inefficient.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but once you are interested in getting automatic bibtex entries, besides the issue of the correct field mapping, the usual advice is: *check*! the info in the fields. ;)

Comment: Now that I saw your edited entries, I ask, are you worried with the field mapping or with the difference "curly brackets" vs "quotation marks"? Curly brackets seem pretty standard to me.

Comment: @gusbrs The bibtex templates from Sharelatex cannot recognize google's curly brackets version of bibtex, sadly...

Comment: I see. I never had problem with them. In this case, I don't know what the issue might be, perhaps someone with more experience than myself will be able to assist. But I believe more information on your particular settings will be required, eventually in the form of a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) / [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: I always use curly brackets. They are perfectly standard. If ShareLaTeX can't deal with them, that's a bug in ShareLaTeX.

Comment: @cfr, I'd say we need more info before we start blaming ShareLaTeX.

Comment: @gusbrs I said 'If'. As a conditional, I stand by what I said. Of course, if the antecedent fails, that's different. But that's so with all conditional statements.

Comment: bibtex allows either quotes or braces, it is not a choice of "bibtex templates" so both forms you show are correct and will work with any bibtex style. If you get an error for some entry for a specific style, perhaps there is a missing field required by that style, but if you do not show the error message it is impossible to help

Comment: @cfr, agreed, of course.  ;)   It is just that, AFAIK, ShareLaTeX is just a frontend with LaTeX running behind it. So why should we expect any peculiarity in this respect in ShareLaTeX? The origin of the problem is very likely something else.

Comment: @gusbrs Oh. I think I'm interpreting the OP differently. I thought the problem involved some kind of auto-complete function or similar, rather than a problem of compilation. (I guess I assumed this for precisely the reason you mention.) But if the problem is compilation-related, we can pretty much exclude the antecedent's being satisfied, as you say.

Comment: @gusbrs But I don't know what a 'bibtex template' is, so I'm pretty clueless, I guess :(.

Comment: Actually, braces are better than quote marks, in my opinion.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as unclear. The statement that curly braces are non-standard is wrong. A claim was made that the problem is with sharelatex, but obody can reproduce it. The question and the answer do not provide anything useful for other readers.

Answer (score 2):

Since both curly brackets and quotation marks are ok, you can leave them and use both formats even if they are mixed like in this case:

```
@book{cbook,
    title = "Modal Logic",
    author = "Patrick Blackburn, Maarten de Rijke e Yde Venema",
    isbn = {0521527147},
    series = {Cambridge Tracts in Theorical Computer Science},
    year={2004},
    publisher={Cambridge University Press},
    keywords = {modal, logic}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and should rather be a comment, I would think. Except that the point has already been made several times in the comments, of course.

Comment: @cfr As the question stands now I think this does answer the question. The comments seem to suggest differently, but I'm not sure about the 'ShareLaTeX cannot recognize curly braces' claim.

Comment: I only just realised: The `author` field is incorrect. Names should always be separated with `and` regardless of the expected output, so in this case it should be `author = "Patrick Blackburn and Maarten de Rijke and Yde Venema",`